Story about a female lead who accidentally gets the attention of a very notorious king who killed her family in her previous life
Hey I was just randomly reminded of this story and I can’t for the life of me remember what it was called or the platform I read it on.
It was focused on a female lead who accidentally gets the attention of a very notorious king who in her previous life killed her family. All I remember is that she lost her memory  (might be an excuse for reincarnation) and used to date a knight who was actually serving that king under cover. Also she was compared to a deer? The female lead had blonde hair and I think the male had red hair.
I know it's super vague, but if you you have any ideas please let me know! 

Is this a manhwa?

I accidentally removed that detail but the original title included "manga/manhwa"

Yes it was :) a manga/manhwa

I remember when the fl and ml meet the female lead is in the outfit of another country as a disguise and is (saved?) from assassins, this is when she is compared to a deer. The ml lead then locks her in a room, tho she escaped with the help of that knight

So the male lead and the knight are two different characters?

Yes, the male lead is the king of different country, and the knight works undercover for the king

I'm confused by the part about the knight serving the King undercover. If he's a knight, wouldn't it be obvious that he serves the King? (Or at least, that he's supposed to?) Or was he pretending to be something other than a knight?

He’s a knight for the female lead but it is found out later that he was actually a spy for the male lead (king of different country) he was there to get information on the fl’s country.

Do you know about where in the story the knight's position as a spy is revealed? Wild guess: The Red Knight Seeks No Reward. It has a time rewind, red hair male lead on the current cover. I don't think the guy that killed her killed the rest of her family, and if he was a spy or anything it was revealed after I stopped reading.

Is this A Heart for the Emperor...?

Our protagonist ended her day as usual, rereading her favorite novel to get to sleep. But, after awakening in the body of the young Charlioni, princess of the Kingdom of Linoa, she knew it was only a matter of time before her kingdom’s ruthless defeat at the hands of Casikaf, blood-thirsty Emperor of Pretas. Such a defeat would surely spell suffering for her as this character was known as the emperor’s prisoner bride, forced to bear his child and wither away, locked within the palace. The new Charlioni concludes that the only way to save herself and her loved ones is to seduce the emperor herself and try to reason with him to end the war. Fortunately, she has the upper hand of knowing that he’ll fall madly in love with her at first sight just like he did in the original novel. There’s just one problem. The emperor is totally her type! With lives and hearts at stake, who is really seducing who? And will her efforts be enough when the novel starts veering off track and every character is not who they appeared to be?


The protagonist wakes up in the world of a novel she'd read as Charlioni Lote Linoa, the blonde-haired Princess of the Kingdom of Linoa.
According to the plot of the novel, the red-haired Emperor of the Empire of Pretas, Casikaf, is supposed to conquer Linoa and massacre Charlioni's family, but falls in love with her at first sight and takes her back to Pretas to make her his wife, after which she eventually kills herself.
Having woken up as Charlioni prior to those events, the protagonist intends to avoid that fate. She doesn't possess Charlioni's memories, so she tells people she has amnesia to explain why she doesn't recognise everyone or recall her personal history with them.
Learning that her older brother has been invited to attend a banquet at Pretas, she asks to go too, seeing this as an opportunity to learn more about Casikaf and figure out whether he's really as ruthless as the novel made him seem. Her parents agree, on the condition that she goes in disguise.
She initially travels to Pretas disguised as a maid, but changes into a dress from the Kingdom of Tulia, which includes a veil covering the lower half of her face, hoping this will allow her to attend the banquet and observe Casikaf without drawing his attention.
However, he notices and becomes enamoured with her anyway, and although she tries to run away from him, he catches up to her in the palace gardens just in time to save her from some assassins. Her terrified appearance reminds him of a baby deer, so he starts calling her that as a pet name.



It's later revealed that the Commander of the Knights of Linoa, Arlein Baellas, is a spy of Casikaf's who infiltrated Linoa years earlier and worked his way up to his current position. However, he has feelings for Charlioni and is protective towards her, since they had dated one another previously.



You can read the manhwa at Tappytoon and WEBTOON.

Only partial match, but oh well...
"7th Time Loop - The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Maried to Her Worst Enemy":

Has light novel and BW manga
Female lead reincarnates to the past after dying
in previous life she was a knight and was killed by tyrant king. Her family also dies, but that is not important to he or us
in current life she marries said tyrant
sadly I don't recall any knight/spy there

